# Clamping my camera to a min and max value

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I tried many approaches, watched tutorials but can't wrap my head around to make the clamp work with my code that I have right now.

So I can zoom in and out but infinitely, how to clamp the camera to max value -5 which is slightly above my player, and min value around -15 which is far above my player.

```
// Control the distance between the object && camera
    private void ZoomIntoObject(float maxZoom, float minZoom)
    {     
        float scrollInput = Input.GetAxis("Mouse ScrollWheel");
        //zPos = scrollInput;
        // zPos = Mathf.Clamp(zPos, minZoom, maxZoom);

        // While scrollwheel
        if (scrollInput > 0.0f)
        {
            // Move forward on the z-as && Clamp maxZoom
            transform.position += transform.forward;
        } else if (scrollInput < 0.0) {
            // Move forward on the z-as && Clamp maxZoom
            transform.position -= transform.forward;
        }

        Debug.Log(zPos);
    }
```

Comment: Did you find a solution to this?

Comment: No, but I kind of tweaked it by using localPosition and move the camera on the z-as and y-as togheter.

Answer (score 0):

Calculate your new position, clamp its z component, then assign to position.

```
private void ZoomIntoObject(float maxZoom, float minZoom)
{     
    float scrollInput = Input.GetAxis("Mouse ScrollWheel");

    Vector3 newPos = transform.position;
    if (scrollInput > 0.0f)
    {
        newPos  += transform.forward;
    } else if (scrollInput < 0.0) {
        newPos  -= transform.forward;
    }
    
    newPos.z = Mathf.Clamp(newPos.z, minZoom, maxZoom);
    transform.position = newPos;
}
```

Comment: The scroll appears now glitchy, i think it because of changing the position to clamp.

Comment: The check on scroll input is a bit redundant ... Couldn't you just do `var newPos = transform.localPosition + Vector3.forward * scrollInput; newPos.z = Mathf.Clamp(newPos.z, minZoom, maxZoom); transform.localPosition = newPos;` .. using `localPosition` seems also to be more correct .. the camera might be rotated somehow

Comment: using local position, I turn my camera in 45 degrees, it is moving forward but not on 45, it just moves forward like normal.